# JS timeout causes eval exception

Tags: settimeout, eval, content-security-policy

For some reason, one of my JS files is triggering an `unsafe-eval` Content Security Policy violation on my site. I thought this odd because there is no `eval()` anywhere in the file. The error happens on the following line:

```
setTimeout(callSpecific(), (lengthMF * (number.length + 2)));
```

The only thing I can see here is the arithmetic on the RHS that sets the timeout value. So, I tried:

```
setTimeout(callSpecific(), (parseInt(lengthMF) * (parseInt(number.length) + 2)));
```

Same thing. The variables themselves are not even strings - they are defined as:

```
var lengthMF = 150;
var number = ""; // yes, this is a string but number.length is not!
```

Why is this triggering a CSP violation? I have other `setTimeout()`s on the page and this seems to be the only problematic one. The weird thing is replacing the arithmetic expression temporarily with a constant (e.g. `50`) does *not* cause the issue to go away.

If it's necessary, `callSpecific()` looks something like this:

```
function callSpecific() {
    if (number == 0) {
        operatorRing();
    } else if (number.length == 2 && number.charAt(1) == 0) {
        playReorder();
    } else if (number.length == 3) {
        //
    } else if (number.length <7 || number.length > 11) {
        //
    } else if (number.length == 11 && (number.charAt(4) == 1 || number.charAt(4) == 0)) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Option 1: You're passing `callSpecific()`, which is called before `setTimeout()`, and because `number == 0`, `operatorRing()` causes some funny business.

Comment: Option 2: Somehow `callSpecific()` returns a string, which means that when the time comes to run the code, `eval()` will be called on that string.

Comment: @root Unfortunately, neither of those is the case. In my testing `number` wasn't 0, and `callSpecific()` doesn't actually return anything

Comment: `callSpecific()` returns nothing (i.e. `undefined`)? So you're not passing anything for `setTimeout()` to execute?